# Django Form Media creating Exception Value: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'lead_management/admin/extra.css'

Tags: django

I have the following within a Form I am using

```
class Media:
    css = {
        'all' : ('lead_management/admin/extra.css',)
    }
```

I have recently upgraded from Py3.6, Django 2.1.10 to  Py3.8, Django 3.1.7.  It used to work and it continues to work in development (DEBUG=True).  It also works locally with DEBUG=False.  But when running in production I am now getting

> Exception Value: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for
> 'lead_management/admin/extra.css'

This is running on an EC2 instance with the staticfiles in S3.  Dev is the same and it was the case prior to upgrade.

Why am I getting this error?

**EDIT**

Responding to question

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'core.storage.StaticStorage'

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    """
    This is our default storage backend for all media in the system.

    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE expects a class and not an instance
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('file_overwrite', False)
        kwargs.setdefault('url_protocol', 'https:')
        kwargs.setdefault('querystring_auth', False)
        kwargs.setdefault('location', get_storage_env('media'))
        kwargs.setdefault('default_acl', 'public-read')
        kwargs.setdefault('object_parameters', {
            'CacheControl': 'max-age=31536000'
        })
        super(MediaStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _save_content(self, obj, content, parameters):
        """
        We create a clone of the content file as when this is passed to boto3 it wrongly closes
        the file upon upload where as the storage backend expects it to still be open
        """
        # Seek our content back to the start
        content.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)

        # Create a temporary file that will write to disk after a specified size
        content_autoclose = SpooledTemporaryFile()

        # Write our original content into our copy that will be closed by boto3
        content_autoclose.write(content.read())

        # Upload the object which will auto close the content_autoclose instance
        super(MediaStorage, self)._save_content(obj, content_autoclose, parameters)

        # Cleanup if this is fixed upstream our duplicate should always close
        if not content_autoclose.closed:
            content_autoclose.close()

class StaticStorage(ManifestFilesMixin, MediaStorage):
    """
    This is like our normal storage but with our manifest mixin for the hash stamps on
    the end of a filename (used for cache busting)
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('file_overwrite', True)
        kwargs.setdefault('location', get_storage_env('static'))
        #kwargs.setdefault('preload_metadata', True)
        super(StaticStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Running `collectstatic --verbosity 2` just shows all files being copied.  No errors

Comment: Can you run `collectstatic` with `DEBUG=False` and high verbosity and add the output to your question? Also, what setting for `STATICFILES_STORAGE` are you using in your production environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running on ElasticBeanstalk and I'm finding this problem repeatedly and also finding the solution is to deploy twice.  I get the manifest error the first time which sorts itself the second.  I do not know why